# accessing element attributes with mootools selector

Tags: javascript, mootools, element, getelementsbytagname

I'm trying to attach a mouseover event to all img elements of a gallery in a page (using Mootools). This is easy enough using something like

```
$$('img.mygalleryclass').addEvents({
mouseover: function(){
    alert(id);
    }
});
```

My question is, how do I alert the id of the element referenced in the $$ 'loop'? That "alert(id)" returns an error every time since id is not defined.

Thanks!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Pass the `event` argument to the `mouseover` function and then get the `id` of the `target`:

```
$$('img.mygalleryclass').addEvents({
    mouseover: function(e) {
        alert(e.target.id);
    }
});
```

[**Here's an example.**](http://jsfiddle.net/gsPKQ/)

Comment: Does MooTools really not bind "this" to the element?

Comment: @sdleihssirhc-- you're right too, it does bind this, so I can use this.id as well.

Comment: `this.get("id")` or just `this.id` - in bound callbacks in mootools, `this` is referencing the element that triggers the event (this === e.target)